# rails adding /admin to routes when admin logs in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my project I have a users model and an advertisements model. The users model contains the admins too. I want to set routes such that when an admin logs in, all URLs contain "/admin" in them. I am new to rails and having some trouble with the same. For example, when a regular user signs in, the url is /advertisements/:id/show but when an admin signs in, the URL becomes /admin/advertisements/:id/show. Tried a lot of methods but couldn't find any solution to do it. 
My User migration file is as follows:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

`def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name, limit: 15, null: false
      t.string :last_name, limit: 15
      t.string :username, limit: 20
      t.string :email, null: false
      t.string :password_digest
      t.boolean :approved, default: false
      t.boolean :admin, default: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end`

My Advertisements migration file is:

```
class CreateAdvertisements < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :advertisements do |t|
      t.string :name, null: false
      t.text :description, null: false
      t.integer :price, null: false
      t.string :location, null: false
      t.integer :user_id
      t.boolean :approved, default: false
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("advertisements", "user_id")
  end
end
```

the routes file (routes.rb) has the code

```
resources: users
resources: advertisements
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Do you want separate routes to lead to separate controllers or do you want same controller to be accessible with different routes?

Comment: I would like the same controllers to be accessible by separate routes, like the advertisements may have to be deleted by both admin or the user who posted it.

Comment: On one hand yes... but on another hand user should have access only to his own posts, while admin -- to all posts. I usually go with 2 variants: 1. either setup separate admin panel namespace or 2. use the same routes, but just hide admin logic for none admin user. What are your reasons to have 2 routes for 1 controller? Admin/none admin roles can be easily handled on one route

Answer (score 0):

To define such routes you can you with:

```
resources: advertisements

scope :admin
  resources: advertisements
end
```

Then setup some kind of filter, that will force users to use `/advertisements` link and force admin to user `/admin/advertisements` in `advertisements_controller`:

```
before_action :require_proper_route_for_role, only: [:index, :new, :show, :edit]

private
def require_proper_route_for_role
  request_params = "?#{params.to_query}"
  if user.admin? && request.path !~ /^\/admin/
    redirect_to "/admin#{request.path}#{request_params}"
  elsif request.path =~ /^\/admin/ && !user.admin?
    redirect_to "#{request.path.sub('/admin','')}#{request_params}"
  end 
end
```

This code is not perfect at all, but it's the best I could do in limited time... but, as I said, I think you are doing some wrong things, that should be rethought in general

Comment: Thanks for the help. Working beautifully except for the URLs where parameters are being sent along with the URL.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I haven't taken it into account. But it will be pretty hard to handle all of this in create/update/destroy. You can't do redirect for POST/PUT/DELETE

Comment: So it's again a question of why do you need such different routes for the very same logic?

Comment: A group I am working with wants all urls to be /admin/url when the admin logs in but doesn't want a different table for admins. so I am stuck in this long process of different routes for same logic.

Comment: Why do you want just to go with admin namespace with separate controllers, that will work with same tables?.... You don't need to setup separate tables for `advertisements` and `admin/advertisements`

Comment: sorry for the delay. Can you help me with the code for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Just an edit to "AntonTkachov's" answer. The code failed at some parts as `request.path` drops the parameters and just gets the relative path, the parameters were getting lost. Also the 'post', 'patch' and 'put' methods were getting changed to 'get' methods that were blocking the creating and updating of new advertisements. A few small change allowed me to correct the problem, which are as follows:

```
before_action: :require_proper_route_for_role, except: [:create, :update]

private

def require_proper_route_for_role
  url_path = request.url
  params_path = url_path.split('?').last
  if current_user.admin? && request.path !~ /^\/admin/
    if params_path == url_path
      redirect_to "/admin#{request.path}"
    else
      redirect_to "/admin#{request.path}?#{params_path}"
    end
  elsif request.path =~ /^\/admin/ && !current_user.admin?
    redirect_to "#{request.path.sub('/admin','')}"
  end
end
```